# Is a 3-character password secure enough for a Macbook's login? Why or why not?

Tags: attacks

My question relates to a concern about theft in specific. I'm not worried about the FBI cracking the password. I'd like to know whether three characters for a local password, a password for **macOS login of a regular macbook device** to be specific, is long and complex enough to prevent somebody who's stolen my property from getting into the machine. I'm also interested in the reasoning behind the answer either way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You haven't mentioned what you're concerned about here.  If your concern is whether someone will be able to reformat and sell the laptop, then yes, that's possible regardless of the password.  It's trivial to do.

If your concern is whether someone will be able to use the laptop without permission but not for the data, then nobody will do that; they'll just reformat it and sell it, or more likely pawn it for quick cash.

If your concern is for the data on the laptop, then this is completely inadequate.  [This article](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hacking-macos-hack-mac-password-without-changing-0189001/), which I found with ten seconds of Googling, shows how to extract the password hash and run it through hashcat.  If you have a password composed of only the 94 non-space printable ASCII characters, there are 830,584 of those.  If you can perform only 1,000 hashes per second, as the article estimates as a lower bound, then that will take a little over 13 minutes.  If someone wants the data on the laptop, whether or not they're the FBI, they can and will crack the password for it, and you'll have added only the most minor impediment.

Comment: Hey about your 3rd paragraph. 1. Is it possible for a common laptop thief (or pawn) to do that? 2. Are we talking about the macOS login password? 3. Doesn't macOS slow down login attempts? If they allow once per minute after 100 wrong attempts, then it would take up to 230 days

Comment: Anyone who wants your data is going to be able to do that, and yes, that's for the login password.  And if they extract the hash and run hashcat on it, then they won't need to worry about whether macOS has brute-force protection.  The brute-forcing happens on a totally different machine.

Comment: Hash of what? Can you elaborate how that works?

Comment: Your password is stored as a password hash and the salt (random data) that feeds into it.  When you log in, the password and salt are hashed, and the result is compared to the stored value to see if it matches.  That attack extracts the hashed value from where it's stored on the system and then tries to attack it on a different system.

Comment: Ohhh they can extract that!? But I assumed un-encrypted FileVault was preventing that. How come it doesn't prevent that? Where is this hash stored? In unencrypted boot partition?

Comment: The link specifies where it can be extracted from on the boot partition.

Comment: So that part on the boot partition is sitting like a duck unencrypted. They can get that string from there and publish it online for all to attack or run it through a regular brute force bot

Answer (score 1):

> Is a 3 character password secure enough for a macbook's login? Why or why not?

> Concern is theft.

The vagueness of the question will make it difficult to answer clearly, if at all. For example, are you worried that someone will sit down at the laptop when you go to the bathroom and make password attempts "live"? Are you worried that someone will steal the laptop and try to extract the password hash and crack it "offline"? In this latter case, do you have full disk encryption turned on? Etc. Etc. Etc.

---

Considering the "live" crack case first: According to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8292683) discussion, macOS, by default, has no limit on password attempts. A user on this discussion thread claims to have been able to make 150 tries without ever being locked out.

If your macbook is configured this way, then you might be concerned.

However, there is still a lot of vagueness to the question even in this case, for example you have not provided enough information regarding what "characters" means. For example does "character" mean only lowercase English alphabet characters or both lower and upper case English alphabet characters or all alphanumeric characters or all alphanumeric and special ASCII symbols or all Chinese characters or all unicode characters in all languages? In the first case (lowercase alphabet characters), there are 17576 possible passwords, and I would expect to guess a random password within about 8788 guesses. If there is no limit on attempts and the OS doesn't significantly slow down the guesses, then you might be concerned since it would only take about a day to make this many guesses (assuming about 5 seconds per attempt).

---

Considering the "offline" case next: In this case you are really in trouble. If someone can get your password hash, they can crack it no problem (as explained in more detail in one of the other answer).

---

Bottom line: 3 character password is probably a bad idea.